# Schema Modification when creating External Tables

Tags: databricks-unity-catalog

I have a folder containing `delta` files. I try to create an external table as follows:

```
spark.sql("""
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table
          (
            id INT,
            name STRING    
          )
          USING DELTA
          LOCATION 'abfss://xxx@yyy.dfs.core.windows.net/aaa/cc'  """)
```

However, I get the following error:

> The specified schema does not match the existing schema at
> abfss://xxx@yyy.dfs.core.windows.net/aaa/cc

The problem is that the `delta` files foresee an additional column (`age`) which I don't want to have in my table. How can I achieve that?